# django: Optimal way to select manytomany object with a particular attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model app which has many to many association with users. Here is the code.

```
class app(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile)
```

Now I want to check if a Django user with particular 'id' exits in this app's user list. After some hits and trials, I got to a solution.

```
 def user_exists(self,user_obj):
     userset = self.app.users.all()
     for userprof in userset:
         if userprof.user == user_obj:
             return True
     return False
```

How can I improve upon this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is very inefficient: it gets all related users and iterates through.

A ManyToManyField returns a queryset. So you can use the normal queryset filtering methods, to do all that in a single command:

```
return self.app.users.filter(user=user_obj).exists()
```

Note this uses the `exists()` method to return a bool directly from the database, rather than evaluating the actual objects.

Comment: Ouch! That was pretty straightforward solution.